# Remover espaço de uma string php

Tags: php, string, query

Estou com um problema para com uma consulta `SQL` com base em um `array`.

Estou concatenando os valores recebidos de um text-area, montando o `sql` com um `IN`, segue exemplo do sql:

```
select * from jupiter where imei in ('352997100159046 ','351758105120669 ','357770077861257 ','358492061345614')
```

E com base nessa consulta retorno os dados pra uma tabela. Acontece se que repararem tem um espaço `' '` após a numeração, e por algum motivo não retorna os dados no PHP *(Na ide do banco retorna normalmente)*.

Tentei de diversas formas retirar esse espaço, segue exemplos:

```
$final = str_replace(' ', '', $manipulado2);

$str = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $final));
```

Criei também um array com caracteres que não quero e removi eles porém também sem sucesso:

```
$caracteres             = array(" ","a", "b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z",".",";"," ", "^", "~","-","!","@","#","$","%","¨","&","*","(",")","=","+","\r\n");
```

Porém de forma alguma consigo retirar esses espaços da minha query.

Esses dados estão errados em um vetor, segue imagem explicativa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem reparar no ultimo não contem o espaço e ele retorna a busca certinha.

**Segue como está sendo feito a concateção (de forma bem primitiva porém é como consegui fazer):**

Recebo via post os dados de um textarea que é separado por enters, e substituo a quebra de linha por `','`.

```
$resultado              = str_replace("\n","','", $_POST['imeis']);
```

Aqui eu chamo a função que essa linha acima está e separo na virgula e coloco isso em um array.

```
$array_informado = explode(',', trata_imei());
```

Depois jogo isso pra um `foreach` pra exibir na minha `table`:

```
print_r($array_informado);
foreach ($array_informado as $rows){
```

Esse print_r, é o que printa na imagem acima, ele já trás a informação com os espaços!!

Alguém sabe por que motivo esses espaços não estão sendo apagados da minha string?

Obrigado!

Comment: O problema pode estar na concatenação. Deveria mostrar na pergunta como isso está sendo feito (colocar um exemplo do textarea com os dados -- se tem quebra de linha etc. -- e o código que faz a concatenação).

Comment: Vou colocar já!

Comment: @Sam Editado!!!

Comment: um trim nao resolve?

Comment: Tentei com trim, não resolve também :\

Comment: Tenho a impressão que ele identifica como se fosse um caractere diferente, ou entao entenda que o caractere seja o numero completo + o espaço, e não apenas o espaço...

Comment: No `preg_replace`, a regex `/\s\s+/` exige que haja pelo menos 2 espaços (um `\s` corresponde a um espaço, o outro `\s+` é "um ou mais espaços", ou seja, tem que ter pelo menos 2, por isso ele não substitui nada). *Talvez* se fizer apenas `preg_replace('/\s+$/', '', $final)` já resolva - se bem que o `trim` deveria remover de qualquer jeito. Não sei, o `trim` só remove alguns caracteres (veja na [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)) mas o Unicode define outros caracteres de "espaço", talvez seja um desses: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Zs/list.htm

Comment: achei algo parecido [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859098/why-is-php-trim-is-not-really-remove-all-whitespace-and-line-breaks)

Comment: Acredito que o caminho seja esse... Tentei da seguinte forma `$str = preg_replace('/^[\pZ\pC]+|[\pZ\pC]+$/u', '', $final); ` porém sem sucesso. o retorno foi `'352997100159046 ','357770077861257 ','351758105120669'`

Comment: Vou dar um edit no post, vejam por favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faz dois replaces, onde o primeiro remove o `\r` (`carriage return`, que é o que está gerando o espaço extra), e outro substituindo a quebra de linha `\n` por `','`.

Exemplo:

```
$resultado = str_replace("\n", "','", str_replace("\r","", $_POST['imeis']));
```

Aí é só adaptar na função onde você está tratando o resultado para gerar a string que você quer.

Comment: Funcionou, tu é o cara! Obrigado!!!